# insert many data in one column in one row (array like)pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to save multiple entries in one column only?

I have an array and i save like this

```
foreach($studentlist as $value) {
    $stmt7 = $dbh - > prepare("INSERT INTO student_tbl (student_id,student_name) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt7 - > bindValue(1, $value['studentid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt7 - > bindValue(2, $value['studentname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt7 - > execute();
}
```

this will result in number of rows depending on the number of students.
How can i make it in way that all the `$value['studentname']` will be saved in `one column in one row`. It can be separated by coma. Is is possible to save `array like` in data base

Comment: you want to insert data like 1,2,3,4?

Comment: yes just like that i cant figure out how to save it like that. i dont even know if it is possible, if there are bad implications in doing so

Comment: @HogRider Don't do that! Keep your [DB normalized!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) *if there are bad implications* Yes there are! It will be very hard to do querys with your db

Comment: @Rizier123 just as i thought there is a bad implication right?arg then i have to stick the current one .can i ask what are the negative result if i do it like that?

Comment: Are you looking for to replace INSERT INTO student_tbl (student_id,student_name) VALUES (?,?) WITH    INSERT INTO student_tbl (student_id,student_name) VALUES (array of studentid, studentname}) ?

Comment: @HogRider 1. You will have a very hard time to do querys and find stuff in your db 2. You will have redundant data and you will end up with just  a mess of a DB. I would recommend you to normalize your db to the 3d NF (4,5 and 6 are a bit of an overkill)

Comment: @Rizier123 you have my gratitude sir i am glad i decided to clear this out first before doing it in my project.

Comment: See also [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462).

Comment: @eggyal really helpful i cant find the exact key word to search that is why i didnt end up on the link but i am glad i was able to read it. reading the first line about data type is one important thing for me you have my gratitude as well

Comment: I think you can use json_encode..